# XSL group elements with specific condition

Tags: xslt

This is my xml:

```html
<Items>
<Item> 
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Code>A</Code>
  <Value>5</Value>
  <Unit>T</Unit>
</Item>
<Item>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Code>A</Code>
  <Value>50</Value>
  <Unit>T</Unit>
</Item>
<Item>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Code>B</Code>
  <Value>10</Value>
  <Unit>U</Unit>
</Item>
<Item>
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Code>B</Code>
  <Value>10</Value>
  <Unit>T</Unit>
</Item>
<Item>
  <Id>4</Id>
  <Code>C</Code>
  <Value>10</Value>
  <Unit>T</Unit>
</Item>
</Items>
```

How to display grouped elements by Code and sum Value property but If Unit= U I must omit next 2 elements. I use xsl 1.0. In this example I must ommit next two items after third Item so, last two Items. I must do this before grouping.

```
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Unit = 'T'">

      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>

        <xsl:value-of select="concat( $lines, '|', LineNumber)"/>|

      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>

  <xsl:value-of select="$lines"/>
```

Any ideas? Now I have  Id node. I want put into lines variable  all id to group but  i dont know how to skip next two elements if Unit  is T

Comment: Please add information about the XSLT version you use or can use to achieve this as some grouping is done much more easily in XSLT 2 or 3 than in XSLT 1. And I think you need to explain with some more details what you want to achieve, at least add the result you want for the shown input, I so far don't understand which elements you want to omit and whether you want to omit them before grouping or after grouping. Also what happens if there are several adjacent `Item[Unit = 'U']`?

Comment: Can you provide some example lines of the desired output?